# Is there a possibility to Avoid multiple "OR" statement in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that has to filter our results from a text field based on certain keywords used in the textline .. currently the SQL statement looks like the below.

`and (name like '%Abc%') or (name like '%XYZ%') or (name like '%CSV%')...`

Is there a way to avoid multiple or statements and achieve the same results?

Comment: As a side note: this is searching a set of substrings in a set of strings, and by default quite costly. If you are worried about performance and this will be done a lot with a lot of search terms/data, there are some good algorithms to do it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm), though of course it doesn't exactly apply to SQL (on the other hand, you can write .NET code to be ran in SQL Server... :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly more shorthand way of doing this if you have a large amount of different patterns is to use `EXISTS` and a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    (VALUES ('abc'), ('xyz'), ('csv')) m (match)
            WHERE   T.Name LIKE '%' + m.Match + '%'
        );
```

A similar approach can be applied with [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). Since this is usually a requirement where people want to pass a variable number of search terms for a match it can be quite a useful approach:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfString TABLE (value VARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then a procedure can take this type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetMatches @List dbo.ListOfString READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    T
    WHERE   EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    @List AS l
                WHERE   T.Name LIKE '%' + l.value + '%'
            );
END
```

Then you can call this procedure:

```
DECLARE @T dbo.ListOfString;
INSERT @T VALUES ('abc'), ('xyz'), ('csv');
EXECUTE dbo.GetMatches @T;
```

Comment: From the table value constructor: answer.. Can it be edited like this "from (values ('30180577','30251291','30200981')) m  (match)... all the search items in a single bracket.. i tried but its giving an error.. "'m' has more columns than were specified in the column list.".. any solution?

Comment: Nope, you will need to separate the items with a bracket. What is the problem with using the standard syntax?

Comment: I just wanted to skip brackets for some reasons. Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could put your filter keywords into a table or temp table and query them like this:

```
select      a.*
from        table_you_are_searching a
inner join  temp_filter_table b
on          charindex(b.filtercolumn,a.searchcolumn) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you another option you could also try this, an IN statement mixed with a PATINDEX:

```
Select *
from tbl
Where 0 not in (PATINDEX('%Abc%', name), PATINDEX('%XYZ%', name), PATINDEX('%CSV%', name))
```